# Continuous spaced input of integers in 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, input, integer, 2d

In a 2D array in C, the input is a continuous set of integers separated by space for each line. What is the code that I should write?

The input is:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

I used this:

```
int i, k;
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < 52; k = k + 2) {
        scanf("%d", &Arr[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int Arr[26][26];`... `for(k=0;k<52;k=k+2)` --> `for(k=0;k<26; k++)` Spaces are skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct:

- you should only increment `k` by `1`, and stop at `26`.
- you should check `scanf` return value.

Try this:

```
    int Arr[26][26];
    int i, k, error = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &Arr[i][k]) != 1) {
                error = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (error)
            break;
    }
    if (error) {
        // the matrix was not correctly parsed, 
        // issue an error message, clean up and exit
    }
```

Alternate solution moving the parsing code to a separate function and retuning a completion code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int load_matrix(int a[26][26]) {
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i][k]) != 1) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// calling this function from main:
int main(void) {
    int Arr[26][26];

    if (load_matrix(Arr)) {
        // the matrix was not correctly parsed, 
        // issue an error message, clean up and exit
        return 1;
    }

    // handle matrix
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot..it worked! Can u just elaborate on why u used the error part in the code?

Comment: I used the `error` variable to exit the nested loops in case of scanning error instead of repeatedly failing to parse.  I could have used a `goto` statement for this purpose, but an `error` variable is more explicit.  Another alternative is to move the parsing code to a separate function and return a completion code.